Reduce Spyder plot memory usage
I want to plot an array many times in a row as it changes on Spyder.
Every time I do this, it is in a new plot. After many iterations the system stops, I presume because it is out of memory.
How do I "reuse" the plot or remove it from memory, so I don't run out of memory?
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as rn

arr= np.zeros(100)
plt.axis([1,100,1,100])

for iterations in range (10): #in my program a much bigger number
    for n in range (100): #make a new version of the array
        arr[n] = rn.randrange(0,99)
        plt.plot(arr) #plot the new version
        plt.pause(.0001)


This question is similar to: How to clear memory completely of all matplotlib plots. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I think you're looking for plt.clf. Placing one at the top of each iteration will clear the current plot so you can aren't redrawing over the same plot over and over again. This will require you to reset the array as well - otherwise, you end up drawing two plots simultaneously, which isn't ideal.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as rn

arr= np.zeros(100)
plt.axis([1,100,1,100]) 

for iterations in range (10):
    arr = np.zeros(100)
    plt.clf()
    for n in range (100):
        arr[n] = rn.randrange(0,99)
        plt.plot(arr)
        plt.pause(.0001)

You also get a different feel by clearing in the inner loop instead. This will make pyplot rewrite individual items instead of clearing the whole array in one go.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as rn

arr= np.zeros(100)
plt.axis([1,100,1,100]) 

for iterations in range (10):
    for n in range (100):
        arr[n] = rn.randrange(0,99)
        plt.clf()
        plt.plot(arr)
        plt.pause(.0001)


Thank you for the suggestion. But it still runs out of memory!  In spyder the previous plots are still visible down the side of the plot pane. does this mean they are still held in memory.?
